Will Sram Dub Pressfit BB92 fit a Sram Apex Crankset?
I would love your help. Will this  Sram Dub Pressfit BB92:

Fit the Sram Apex Crankset:


This question is similar to: Bottom bracket sizing: Samox, SRAM, and Shimano confusion. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This was actually answered on your first question. BB92 is an MTB standard. The Eagle crank is an MTB crank. The question is does your frame take BB92. I believe it doesn't, given the initial spec.

Thank you @WeiwenNg! You are right, the standard is  PF 86

Can I ask you, if I buy the Shimano SM-BB72-41B, will a Sram Apex Crankset  fit?

That was also covered in the previous question and answer.

Not to mention that Apex crank is a GXP only so doesn't fit DUB anyway. @WeiwenNg

But he could use an Apex 12sp DUB Wide crankset to fit the mtb bottom bracket.

@WeiwenNg so i think there is good ground for a useful answer
